# How to export multiple Barcharts from Mathematica to $\LaTeX$

Tags: latex, export

I have to make a document with multiple bar charts and export it:

```
A = BarChart[Table[CAB[[1, i]], {i, 16}], ChartLabels -> {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
    "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16"}];
Export["Barcharts_2.tex", A];
```

This is not a problem, but when I try to export multiple bar charts (in my case sixteen):

```
A = (BarChart[Table[CAB[[1, i]], {i, 16}]]
     BarChart[Table[CAB[[2, i]], {i, 16}]])
Export["Barcharts_2.tex", A];
```

I get this error:

```
TeXForm::unspt
```

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
 2)[`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking 
the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system 
is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to 
accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, 
[`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

May be its a matter of using `GraphicsRow`?

```
  plot = GraphicsRow[{ BarChart[Table[i, {i, 5}], ChartStyle -> "DarkRainbow"],
  BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}}] }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
  Export["test.tex",plot];
```

works.

I didn't know you could export directly graphs to TeX so I learnt something! ;-)

Comment: Actually, what the `Export` does here is create (1) a skeleton `.tex` document `text.tex` that has an `\includegraphics` command; and (2) an `.eps` file with the actual graphics. That is pretty neat!

Comment: Thank you very much, it solved my problem entirely. I'm quite new to Mathematica :) Glad to help you too!!

Comment: This seems a little hit and miss, `GraphicsGrid` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @image_doctor it does for mac-os 10.7.5 + mathematica 8.0.4 (?) i.e. it produces a latex file and an eps file which you can process?

Comment: `GraphicsRow` seems to work fine, but `GraphicsGrid` doesn't - Linux -  8.0.4