# Export Plot from Table to $\LaTeX$ -- conform with pgfplots

Tags: export, latex, compatibility

### General purpose

My intension is to use data created by Mathematica as in

- [Export Plots to $\LaTeX$](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5132/export-plots-to-latex),
- [$\LaTeX$ and Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/736/latex-and-mathematica), or
- [How to export multiple Barcharts from Mathematica to $\LaTeX$](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14054/how-to-export-multiple-barcharts-from-mathematica-to-latex)

but with a nicer $\LaTeX$ conform font style and similar stuff. This is the reason why I am using the $\LaTeX$ package [pgfplots](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots). This package also allows me to add further information and fancy graphical stuff (by using TikZ) to the plot at later time.

### Issue

Now I do not get Mathematica to write me a data-file which can be read by the $\LaTeX$ package [pgfplots](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots). The current data (and export) has the following structure:

```
DataTable = {{9/50, 5.00251*10^9, 3.02252*10^9, 2.17472*10^9, 1.97472*10^9},<<1000>>};
Export["Energy.csv", DataTable];
```

The idea is to plot in the end something like

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    xlabel={xlabel},
    ylabel={ylabel}]
\addplot[color=blue,mark=none] 
    table [x expr=\thisrowno{0}, y expr=\thisrowno{1}, col sep=space] {data.dat};
\addplot[color=blue,mark=none] 
    table [x expr=\thisrowno{0}, y expr=\thisrowno{2}, col sep=space] {data.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### EDIT:

The $\LaTeX$ routine [pgfplots](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) uses the following data structure (where the option `col sep=space|tab|comma|colon|semicolon|braces|&|ampersand` defines the separation character - same is also vaid for the column separation `row sep=newline|\\`):

```
Field,Energy1,    Energy2,    Energy3,    Energy4
9/50, 5.00251e+09,3.02252e+09,2.17472e+09,1.97472e+09
... (all data like this first row of data)
```

You might want to check out chapter 4.3.2 (Reading Coordinates From Tables) in the [pgfplots manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf) which contains all important informations. By the way the header is not necessary but helps other readers to understand your data.

Comment: So, what structure would be required for this to be possible, for those of us without a familiarity/working installation of $\LaTeX$?

Comment: The "CSV" export of *Mathematica* creates exactly the structure you like, where one line is exported as `9/50,5.00251e9,3.02252e9,2.17472e9,1.97472e9`. In you pgfplots code, you used `data.dat` which should be `data.csv` with your current approach. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: @halirutan: It was a stupid error that occured because I did not choose the correct file (I still used the `data.dat` file. You are completely right. +1
 I will rephrase an answer out of my question for other interested people (as I invested too much time in that issue).

Comment: @strpeter No problem. This happens to everyone once in a while. The good thing is, that it works now.

Answer (score 6):

### Mathematica export

Just export the data such that in one column you have the x-coordinates and in another you have the y-coordinates.

```
DataTable = {{9/50, 5.00251*10^9, 3.02252*10^9, 2.17472*10^9, 1.97472*10^9},<<1000>>};
DataTableWithHeader = Flatten[{{{"ColumnX", "ColumnY1", "ColumnY2", "ColumnY3", "ColumnY4"}}, DataTable}, 1];
Export["Energy.csv", DataTableWithHeader];
```

### $\LaTeX$ import and compiling

You now can use a compiler like `pdflatex` to create your plots from a $\LaTeX$-file like the folowing - like you desire.

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    xlabel={xlabel},
    ylabel={ylabel}]
\addplot[color=blue,mark=none] 
    table [x expr=\thisrowno{0},y expr=\thisrowno{1},col sep=comma]{Energy.csv};
\addplot[color=blue,mark=none] 
    table [x expr=\thisrowno{0},y expr=\thisrowno{2},col sep=comma]{Energy.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The resulting images might look like the following example.

[image: Illustration created with pgfplots]